# The same values of datetime in queryset

Tags: python, django, datetime, filter, django-queryset

I have problem with count some values in queryset with the same datetime, this is my queryset:

```
energy = self.Gauge.objects.filter(place=place, **datetime_kwargs).values(*self.csv_fields).order_by('datetime')
```

The result is:

```
[{'a': 2, 'b': 3, datetime: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 10, 0, 0)}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, datetime: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 12, 0, 0)}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, datetime: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 10, 0, 0)}, {'a': 5, 'b': 2, datetime: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 12, 0, 0)}]
```

I want to count a and b values from the same date,for example:

date: 10.05.2016 00:00 : a = 5, b = 9.
I'm trying with comprehension list:

```
key_values = ['datetime']

    for e in energy:
        energy_by_date = {k: v for k, v in energy.items() if k in key_values}
```

but it give only dates. How can I group querysets objects by date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "group_by" Django ORM capability, something like :

```
 YourModel.objects.values('datetime').annotate(a_total=Sum('a'), b_total=Sum('b'))
```